# Create P12 or PFK file from CER, PEM, P7B, PKCS8

Tags: key, certificate, pem, cer

I would like to create a .p12 or .pfk file. I have the files as below :

- xx.cer
- xx.p7b
- xx.pem
- xx.pkcs8

I've tried a lot of openssl commands but I could only create a .p12 file of zero bytes.

Example of openssl command that I executed :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey xx.pem -out xx.p12
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is in xx.pem file and what is in xx.pkcs8. Private key should be in one (or both?) of these files. I will assume that the private key is in xx.pem file. Then the command to make a p12 file should be:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./xx.pkcs8 -in ./xx.pem -out ./xx.p12
```

Openssl will promt you to add a password to p12 file but when typing there will be no asterisks on the screen. Don't worry just type the password.
This p12 file will contain private key and corresponding certificate. It will not include chain certificates which could be in xx.p7b file.

Comment: I have tested your command and I got this error :

    unable to load private key
    54085:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Comment: When you open xx.pem in text editor do you see any header like BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY followed by base64 encoded private key? Also check xx.pkcs8.

Comment: In the file xx.pem, there is the following text :

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIByDCCATGgAwIBAgIIUk
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: OK, it could be CA certificate - take a look. What about xx.pkcs8?

Comment: In the xx.pkcs8, there is data hexadecimal like this : 3082 017c 301e 060a 2a86 4886 f70d 010c

Comment: OK, lets try to get hexadecimal to PEM. Use [ASN.1 Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-Editor) and its Data Converter tool to do that. Save the output to a file xx.b64 and add header (-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----) and footer (-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----). Then try the command from my answer but replace xx.pem with xx.b64 in the command. Hopefully the header and footer are correct and xx.pkcs8 really contains private key :)

Comment: OK. I might made a mistake with the headers. If the private key was not encrypted with password hten the header should be (-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY-----). If the private key was encrypted with password then it should have headers (-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----). Please try both.

Comment: I changed the header and the footer by "..ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY" and I executed the command. I entered the password and I get this error :
No certificate matches private key

Comment: OK. It's getting better :) Try to replace xx.cer with xx.pem. xx.cer contains CA certificate probably.

Comment: I not sure if I understand, I run this command "openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./xx.pem -in ./xx.pem -out ./xx.p12" I entered the password, and I still this error "No certificate matches private key"

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try that command. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: My pkcs8 file is encrypted but when I open it with the data converter tool, it does not ask password, then the convert may be incorrect. When I execute the new command I have this error "unable to load private key
59331:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY"

Comment: When you converted from hex to PEM dataconverter adds some dummy headers. Replace those headers with the ones that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the pkcs8 file to pem and b64 and I updated the header and the footer. When I launch the commands as below, I got this error :

Commands :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./xx.pem -in ./xx.cer -out ./xx.p12
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./xx.b64 -in ./xx.cer -out ./xx.p12
```

Results :

```
unable to load private key
58163:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1315:
58163:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:827:
58163:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:747:Field=version, Type=RSA
58163:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/asn1/d2i_pr.c:99:
58163:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/crypto/pem/pem_pkey.c:125:
```